# Slow Loris in Netty as a client or server

Tags: java, netty

I'm still pretty new to netty so please bare with me. There seems to be plenty of questions asking why a specefic netty implementation is slow and how to make it faster. But my use case is a bit different. I want to avoid low level socket implementations (hence netty) but I also know that blocking the event group is bad. I know I can dynamically manage the pipeline. I'm not sure I know enough about netty to know if this is possible, and I've not tried much that I don't already know is bad (`thread.sleep` for example). The protocol is `HTTP` but I also need it to be useful for other protocols.

But what I don't know is, for a single connection on a shared port, how to slow down the response of the server to the client, and vice versa?  Or put more aptly: where, and what, would I implement the slowness required? My guess is the encoder for the where; but because of netty's approach, i haven't the foggiest for the what.

Comment: what is the question? any code?

Comment: I have updated to better reflect the question, I hope. But I don't have any code for it other than silly ill-conceived attempts that sort of work but go against Netty standards.

Comment: What do you mean by slowness? I.e all IO events including read and write or just initial connection? A TrafficShapingHandler might be what you're looking for but the question is still too vague. https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/traffic/AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.html

Comment: Any point in the pipeline life cycle really, but to start I do specifically mention `how to slow down the response of the server to the client`. I will dive into that class. it looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you know that `Thread.sleep` is "bad" but it really depends on what you're trying to achieve and where you put the sleep. I believe that the best way to build this would be to use a `DefaultEventExecutorGroup` to offload the processing of your slow-down ChannelHandler onto non-event-loop threads and then call `Thread.sleep` in your handler.

From the ChannelPipeline javadoc, under the "Building a pipeline" section:
https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html

> A user is supposed to have one or more ChannelHandlers in a pipeline to receive I/O events (e.g. read) and to request I/O operations (e.g. write and close). For example, a typical server will have the following handlers in each channel's pipeline, but your mileage may vary depending on the complexity and characteristics of the protocol and business logic:
>
> Protocol Decoder - translates binary data (e.g. ByteBuf) into a Java object.
> Protocol Encoder - translates a Java object into binary data.
> Business Logic Handler - performs the actual business logic (e.g. database access).
> and it could be represented as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> static final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(16);
> ...
>
> ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
>
> pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MyProtocolDecoder());
> pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MyProtocolEncoder());
>
>  // Tell the pipeline to run MyBusinessLogicHandler's event handler methods
>  // in a different thread than an I/O thread so that the I/O thread is not blocked by
>  // a time-consuming task.
>  // If your business logic is fully asynchronous or finished very quickly, you don't
>  // need to specify a group.
>  pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());
> ```
>
> Be aware that while using DefaultEventLoopGroup will offload the operation from the EventLoop it will still process tasks in a serial fashion per ChannelHandlerContext and so guarantee ordering. Due the ordering it may still become a bottle-neck. If ordering is not a requirement for your use-case you may want to consider using UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor to maximize the parallelism of the task execution.

Comment: Ohhh I see! Specifying the group offloads the thread to that group so the _thread.sleep_ runs on it instead of the IO thread. Thats cool! That'll be useful - I'll see how I can make Slow Loris work on it. But I believe `ChannelTrafficShapingHandler` handles the Slow Loris concept quite nicely. Thank you for your detailed answer and the new knowledge. Have some reputation =D

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone can post a better (more explanative) answer than this but basically all that's needed is to use a ChannelTrafficShapingHandler with some small enough values.

For instance, a 2kb response with read and write limit of 512b, maxTime of 6000ms, and a checkInterval of 1000ms forces the response to take 4000ms with the ChannelTrafficShapingHandler, and 50ms without it when running both client and server locally. I expect those times to increase dramatically when on the network wire.

```
final ChannelTrafficShapingHandler channelTrafficShapingHandler = new ChannelTrafficShapingHandler(
    getRateInBytesPerSecond(), getRateInBytesPerSecond(), getCheckInterval(), getMaxTime());
ch.addLast(channelTrafficShapingHandler);
```